# iPhone 3g with IOS 4.2.1 cycles wifi, cannot connect

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to fix the WiFi on my friends iPhone 3g. It sees all the networks, but I only get "Unable to join network " when I try to connect. So I jailbroke it ;) and installed WiFiFoFum just to see if I could get some more details. And it seems like the phone cycles the wifi drivers or something.

When WiFiFoFum scans the networks, they show up in a list. It does this once every ~3 seconds (it shows a loader when it does). But every 3 or 4 scans, all networks disappear, stay away for about 3 or 4 scans, then pop in again.

Of cource this could be a flaw with WiFiFoFum, but it's very coincidental in that case...

Any suggestions? I'm planning on going in with SSH to see if I can figure out closer what is happening. Should I look for anything special?

EDIT:

Some more info.. I have tried unsecured, wep, wpa and wpa2 protected networks, no difference.

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: I can migrate this question to the Apple Stack Exchange site for you if you'd like, but I'm not sure how they'll take questions relating to jailbreaking.

Comment: @nhinkle: I'm sure they'll be fine, there are a few jailbreaking questions on Apple.SE that aren't closed.

Comment: @nhinkle it's not even at all a question about jailbreak... It's just mentioning it.

Comment: So I did go in with SSH. But my BSD-experience is limited, and BSD-handheld even more so :) So I didn't find out anything special.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the possibility of a software problem by (first backing up and then) restoring to a clean default OS install. It you still can't connect in that state, it's time for a visit to the Genius Bar or a call to AppleCare.

Comment: Tried several times. No genius bar available, and the phone is out of any warranties anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset all settings this usually works for me!